# How can I remove unmodifed binary files from git status?

Tags: git, github, automation, binary-data, build-tools

I have a git project which features=(REQUIRES respository synchronization of) some auto-generated-binary-files.

Sometimes these files are updated by my IDE build process, but the files are not modified. The git command falsely reports these files as modified. I want to keep these files from showing up in `git status` or other `git` queries when they have not ACTUALLY been modified.

`How can I remove unmodifed binary files from git status?`

Comment: I guess you know what you are doing but someone new to git finding this question might not: Whenever possible, do not add binary files to git. You can use a .gitignore file to hide them from git status. Usually binary files can be created from source files (these belong into git) by your IDE or some install/setup/make script.

Comment: @dauer, That's a great thought for newbies. However, my project is a binary project release. There is no way around the need for this. To be clear: I am are not trying to hide or exclude binary files, I am using git for tracking the revisions made to them. The only text files the project has, are the LICENSE, README.MD, support scripts, etc. Please note that being responsible for the thoughts of other people is not specific to the question.

Comment: [You can browse the project here](https://www.github.com/hypersoft/Krypton)

Answer (score 0):

Use [git-checkout-unmodified-binaries](https://gist.github.com/hypersoft/eada0611d159e79ebbb57d9b27c6a73a).

Command Requirements: `bash`, `md5sum`, `git`

The program takes two or more arguments.

The first argument is the path to your git project's root, and all other parameters are files relative to the git root that you want to select for modification testing.

(1) The command will use the `md5sum` program to calculate if the file has actually been modified from a previously stored md5 record,

(2) then it will ask `git` for a list of all modified files, and it will check that list against its list.

(3) If `git` falsely-reports a binary file modification, the program will use `git` to check that file out from the current branch.

NOTE: The first time you run the program, it won't do anything but cache the current MD5 sums of the files you specified. Every time thereafter, it will use that MD5 file to compare the current file set. After comparisons have completed, a new MD5 sum-file is generated.

You will have to slip an exec call to this baby, into your build process somewhere. Usually, right after you finished building everything, and before you commit your changes. If you have a custom commit command, you would likely be running this tool just before you execute that command.

You might be thinking: Why doesn't git do this automatically? You and I are thinking the same thing. There may be an option somewhere for this, but my build/vcs tools don't allow me to configure that stuff so, here is what I came up with.

Source Listing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# This is a Git tool which zaps-auto-generated-binaries, which have not
# been modified from the previous version.

# This tool is designed to help keep commit history clean and concise.

GITROOT="`realpath $1`"; shift;

MD5FILES="$@";

MD5CACHE=${GITROOT}/MD5;

md5.cache() { md5sum -b $MD5FILES > $MD5CACHE; }
md5.unmodified.files() { md5sum -c $MD5CACHE | grep OK | cut -d: -f1; }

git.modified.files() { git ls-files -m; }

params.contains() {
    match="$1"; shift;
    for arg; do [[ "$match" == "$arg" ]] && echo $arg; done;
}

filter.matches() {
  while read line; do
    params.contains "$line" "$@";
  done;
}

(
 cd $GITROOT;
 [[ -e "$MD5CACHE" ]] && {
   FILES=$(git.modified.files | filter.matches $(md5.unmodified.files))
   [[ -n "$FILES" ]] && git checkout $FILES;
 }
 md5.cache;
)
```

-- USAGE UPDATE --

You will need to touch your generated sources AFTER running this command IF:

(1) your build tools won't overwrite/update the binaries, AND

(2) you did not commit your changes after a build (such as during live-application-testing-cycles).

This is because the files in your distribution repository may be touched by the `git checkout ...` operation; which cleans your working tree.

Generally, it is safe to `touch` (unix speak for update the write-time-stamp to the current time for a file) all generated sources after running the command, but that might not be very efficient depending on the number of files you will have to process, and their respective sizes in conjunction with your operating system and hardware. The most notable delays will be file size due to the md5 sum calculations.

To sum this documentation/update, up; you need to update the write timestamp of your generated sources after running this command, so that the next time you run the command, any file that has been re-generated between `git` commits, but not saved in a `git` commit, will run through this filter process again; which will allow you to perform more builds/tests & edits on your live (local binary distribution git root) repository before committing your changes.

-- USAGE UPDATE --

Rather than mess with the file-time-stamps, you can delete your automatically generated file-copies from the distribution root, prior to building. The missing file condition(s), will force most build tools to copy/re-generate. I use several cache folders (libs, docs, etc) for generated files, and I have a distribution step, which simply copies the files over to the distribution git project root. This method is the only one I can get to work consistently with my build tools. (IntelliJ-IDEA) your mileage may vary, however this tool is a great solution if you comprehend how build tools really work.